# Conditional Bean Configuration

Tags: xml, spring, configuration, conditional-statements

I was trying to configure my spring beans. This is what I have now. What it is doing right now is get manifest file and data from the default path. And use in other beans.

```
<bean id="ManifestFactory">
  <constructor-arg name="manifestPath" value="default manifest path"/>
</bean>

<bean id="Manifest" factory-method="create" factory-bean="ManifestFactory"/>

<bean id="some other beans">
  <constructor-arg name="dataPath" value="default data path"/>
  <constructor-arg name="manifest" ref="Manifest"/>
</bean>
```

What I want to do is try to get data from directory 1, if failed, get data from default directory. Then I need to set corresponding manifest path and data path in other bean's constructor-arg.

I'm not sure how this can be done. Any idea will be helpful.

Comment: Can you edit your question to add some code or configuration of what you already have, please?

Comment: I don't think you can do that only in XML as no code is executed in XML so you can't really load data and do something else if it fails.